# MySQL JOIN with GROUP BY taking eternally long to run

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in my database, as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL
  KEY `id` (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
  `user_id` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The users table has about 200,000 rows, and the sessions table has about 10m rows. I'm trying to do a simple JOIN, as follows:

```
SELECT users.id, SUM(sessions.time) AS TotalTime,
  FROM users
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sessions
  ON users.id = sessions.user_id
  GROUP BY users.id
  LIMIT 1;
```

When I run this query, even with LIMIT set to 1, it runs endlessly with no result. If I omit the GROUP BY clause, it runs instantly. Is there something I may be missing here, or is it simply that the sessions table is too large for this to work efficiently?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Try adding an index to `users.id` and `sessions.user_id`.

Comment: @Oleander Doesn't `KEY` imply an index?

Comment: Can you post the EXPLAIN query output?

Comment: Why using Left join? Just asking, can't you reduce to inner join, picking session only for user's who exist.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by adding indexes and primary keys to your tables.
A suggestion would be to make id in the users table as a primary key, add an id column as primary key on the sessions table.  You could also add an index on the userid column of the sessions table.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to put proper indices on your tables, to assure performance. Putting primarey keys onto the id and an index on sessions.user_id should greatly improve your query run time.

Also for referential integrity consider working with foreign keys and constraints.

If your session data is temporary (unless your table acts as some kind of log and the data needs to be kept), consider expiring/deleting unnecessary session entries to minimize the table. Are all the 10M session entries needed at any time? With 200k Users there shouldn't be  more than 200k active sessions, given they are all online at the same time. You could also consider moving inactive entries to another table on a regular basis for long term storage if needed later. This could be done immediately when the user ends his session, for example.

That being said, a table with 10M entries should work just fine, and is far from being considered "too many" on a properly modeled database.

Answer (score 0):

The `KEY` keyword indicates there are indexes on user_id in both tables, so that seems OK.

A `LEFT JOIN` is often more time-consuming than an `INNER JOIN`. In this case I would suggest to try a sub-query like this:

```
SELECT users.id,
       (SELECT  SUM(time)
          FROM  sessions
          WHERE users.id = sessions.user_id) AS TotalTime,
  FROM users
  LIMIT 1;
```

Also, you could ask yourself if you really need to know the session time a user spent 5 years ago. It would be good to limit this to a fixed period, like the total session time during the past 6 months.

You would need to add a column in the `sessions` table to specify when the session took place (a date). And then you would add a filter on that.